# Firebreath : Getting these errors while building Firebreath with example projects

Tags: visual-c++, firebreath

I'm new to this plugin development. so bear with me.

I have downloaded the FireBreath project. It was wonderful. When i build it as the way they said,  I got following three errors.

I have built it using visual studio 2005, I executed the following line in command prompt

```
 "prep2005.cmd examples"
```

The Errors are,

```
1. 'SwitchToThread': identifier not found   d:\Projects\firebreath-FireBreath-b73d799\src\libs\log4cplus\src\threads.cxx    92  


2. Cannot open include file: 'vfwmsgs.h': No such file or directory d:\Projects\firebreath-FireBreath-b73d799\examples\BasicMediaPlayer\Win\error_mapping.cpp   18

3. Cannot open include file: 'dshow.h': No such file or directory   d:\Projects\firebreath-FireBreath-b73d799\examples\BasicMediaPlayer\Win\MediaPlayerWin.cpp  24
```

Whether am i doing right. Am i missed something ?

Answer (score 0):

FireBreath comes with two samples, namely BasicMediaPlayer and FBTestPlugin. When you type prep2005.cmd examples, it builds visual studio project for both the plugins. The BasicMediaPlayer sample uses DirectX to play specified videos in the browser. The two headers which are not found are the directx header. So it seems like those headers are not present on the default location on your system, so firebreath generated project is not able to find it. Check for their exact location and change it in the generated project. It will work. If you build only FBTestPlugin, it will build successfully.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried creating a new plugin and it got built successfully